# Can't referr to my get method

Tags: java, android, class, android-fragments, android-activity

I have this amazing and good looking class:

```
public class SayingsHolder extends Application{

    ArrayList<String> SayingsList = new ArrayList<String>(){{
        SayingsList.add("1");
        SayingsList.add("2");

    }};

    public ArrayList<String> getSayingsList() {
        return SayingsList;
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to call the `getSayingsList` method inside of my activity's `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` by:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {   
    final SayingsHolder holder = (SayingsHolder).getApplication();
}
```

Everything fine for now, but when I make my code like this:

```
 private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {   
        final SayingsHolder holder = (SayingsHolder).getApplication();
        holder.getSayingsList();
    }
```

it says:

```
Syntax error on token "getSayingsList", Identifier expected after this token
```

The problem is that `holder` is not functional at all. What I mean is that when i type the this `holder.` the `getSayingsList` is not showing at all.

What am I missing here? I know that it is an extremely small issue, but it seems that I can't spot it. My activity `extends FragmentActivity` if it's important

It seems that I'm missing something here. I can't call my method **anywhere** in my activity. I'm starting a bounty, because I need an example.

Comment: `I'm starting a bounty, because I need an example.` I think you need a java primer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple answer is "statements are not allowed in class body". The simplest fix for you program would be creating an instance list variable like.

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {   
    final SayingsHolder holder = (SayingsHolder).getApplication();
    ArrayList<String> sayingsList = holder.getSayingsList();
}
```

This is just one option. You can move this `holder.getSayingsList();` to a method body or static block as well. 
Like all the other answeres the issue with you program was a syntax error.

As per Java syntax a class body can have member declaration, static block, method declaration, another class declaration, constructor etc. You could read about this on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html. This may be confusing so first refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-2.html. This gives an idea about each notations.

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter {
    // This is a member declaration. So "holder" is now a class member.
    final SayingsHolder holder = (SayingsHolder).getApplication();

    // This is a constructor
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(){
    }

    // An inner class
    class InnerScreenSlidePagerAdapter{
    }

    // A method
    public void aMethod() {
    }

    // This is a static block
    static {
    }

}
```

All these are valid to be used inside a class. But in your case you are trying to add a statement to a class body. That is not as per syntax rules

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {       
    final SayingsHolder holder = (SayingsHolder).getApplication(); //This line a member declaration. And a valid sysntax. So no issues here

    holder.getSayingsList(); // This is a statement. So this line creates issue as its not part of a class body. 
                // Statements should be enclosed within a method body or static block or for an assigment.

    //But instead if you say it like
    List<String> sayingsList = holder.getSayingsList(); // Now it became a filed(member) declaration. You are trying to declare a member names "sayingsList" just like you created "holder" above
    //So now we converted the statement to a member declaration
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It seems that I have missed these rules. That is exactly what I was looking for. Huge thanks for helping me. I deserve the down votes.

Answer (score 2):

In the definition of a class, you can have methods and properties. "holder.getSayingsList();" is a statement which belongs inside a method. It cannot stand alone in the definition of a class.

Here is an example:

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {   
    final SayingsHolder holder = SayingsHolder.getApplication();

    /* You cannot use holder here. Statements like this must be inside a method.
    holder.getSayingsList();
     */

    /* For the same reason, you cannot do this here:
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
     */

    /* You CAN use holder in an instance method */
    public void foo() {
        holder.getSayingsList();
    }

    /* You can use it in a class method, but you must instantiate a ScreenSlidePagerAdapter object first */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ScreenSlidePagerAdapter obj = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter();
        obj.getHolder().getSayingsList();

        /* you can do this too */
        obj.foo();

    }

    //getter for the holder variable
    public SayingsHolder getHolder() {
        return holder;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have statements that are not declarations outside of a method. The "holder.getSayingsList();" statement must be in a method or static initialization block.